# Updating postgreSQL db to version 14

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos, terminal, postgresql-14

I am attempting to set up my docker environment to work on a project. I downloaded the dump file and ran my sh file to build the image. I am getting an error message

```
"FATAL: database files are not compatible with server. The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 14.8"
```

I attempted to upgrade the database by running "brew postgresql-upgrade-database" via command line. But I get another error message

```
"Warning: Calling brew postgresql_upgrade_database is deprecated! Use using new, versioned e.g. `var/postgres@14` datadir and `pg_upgrade` instead.
Warning: Formula postgresql was renamed to postgresql@14.
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/PG_VERSION"
```

So I ran "pg_upgrade" as instructed in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html. But I am so confused as to how to run it. I believe I have to add arguments after pg_upgrade.. but am I putting the path to the database? for example I have it saved on the desktop, so do I run pg-upgrade User/username/Desktop?

I am new to programming, please help!

I am trying to upgrade my database to be compatible with postgreSQL 14.8

Comment: You can't run upgrade until you have a working server to start with.  Something here: "I downloaded the dump file and ran my sh file to build the image" went wrong, but without any details no one can tell you what it was.